# jquery slider with AmChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I was trying to create a Time-lapse graph slider with jquery as below. This is the minimal example I have put to demonstrate the problem I am facing, however, my actual plot contains much data than reported here.

The problem here is when I move my slider the underlying graph is not moving at all. Can somebody point me what inherent part I have missed out here?

```js
var markers = [{
        "year": 2003,
        "images": [{
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5
          }]
        }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "images": [{
            "europe": 3.5,
            "namerica": 5.5
          }]
        }]

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
    "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
    },
    "dataProvider": markers[0].images,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "title": "Europe",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "europe"
    }, {
        "title": "North America",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "namerica"
    }],
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "position": "left"
    },
    "export": {
      "enabled": true
     },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
      $( "#slider" ).slider({
        "min": 0,
        "max": (markers.length - 1),
        "create": function( event, ui ) {
          var dataSet = markers[0];
          $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.year);
        },
        "slide": function( event, ui ) {
          var dataSet = markers[ui.value];
          e.chart.dataProvider.images = dataSet.images;
          $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.year);
        }
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  height: 400px;
}    
#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}    
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="chartdiv"></div>
      <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the slider?

Comment: @Rohit, Slider should be visible just below the plot window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the solution.

You have missed calling `e.chart.validateData();` after the data changes.  so the chart takes in new data.

And, `e.chart.dataProvider = dataSet.images;` should be like this.

```js
var markers = [{
        "year": 2003,
        "images": [{
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5
          }]
        }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "images": [{
            "europe": 3.5,
            "namerica": 5.5
          }]
        }]

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
    "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
    },
    "dataProvider": markers[0].images,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "title": "Europe",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "europe"
    }, {
        "title": "North America",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "namerica"
    }],
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "position": "left"
    },
    "export": {
      "enabled": true
     },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
      $( "#slider" ).slider({
        "min": 0,
        "max": (markers.length - 1),
        "create": function( event, ui ) {
          var dataSet = markers[0];
          $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.year);
        },
        "slide": function( event, ui ) {
          var dataSet = markers[ui.value];
          e.chart.dataProvider = dataSet.images;
          e.chart.validateData();
          $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.year);
        }
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  height: 400px;
}    
#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}    
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="chartdiv"></div>
      <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```